# Programatically add an editable TextBox to DataTable - Column requires a valid DataType

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, datacolumn

I am trying to populate a `DataGridView` with a dynamically generated `DataTable` and I need one of the column to be a editable `TextBox`

This is a snippet from my application that populates the data grid view:

```
public static void PopulatePOLines(MSSQLConnection mssqlConnection, string supplierAccountNumber, DataGridView poLineList)
{
    // Init
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dataColumn;
    DataRow dataRow;
    List<POLine> poLines = new List<POLine>();

    // Define sage sku column
    dataColumn = new DataColumn();
    dataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.String");
    dataColumn.ColumnName = "sageSku";
    dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

    // Define required quantity column
    dataColumn = new DataColumn();
    dataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dataColumn.ColumnName = "requiredQuantity";
    dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

    // Define on pop quantity column
    dataColumn = new DataColumn();
    dataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    dataColumn.ColumnName = "onPOPQuantity";
    dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

    // Define order quantity column
    dataColumn = new DataColumn();
    dataColumn.DataType = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.TextBox");
    dataColumn.ColumnName = "orderQuantity";
    dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

    // Consolidate & populate po lines from failed allocations by supplier from db
    try
    {
        // Query database
        List<Dictionary<string, object>> results = mssqlConnection.ExecuteReader(
            "... snipped...",
            new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "SupplierAccountNumber", supplierAccountNumber }
            });

        // Parse result
        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> dbRow in results)
        {
            // Parse row field value
            var sageSku = dbRow["SageSku"].ToString();
            var quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dbRow["Quantity"]);

            // Check if this failed allocation line is known
            var poLine = poLines.Find(s => s.SageSku == sageSku);

            // If this line isn't known
            if (null == poLine)
            {
                // Workout quantity on pop for this sage sku
                var onPOPQty = mssqlConnection.ExecuteScalar<int>(
                    "... snipped...",
                    new Dictionary<string, object>()
                    {
                        { "SageSku", sageSku }
                    });

                // Insert a new record
                poLines.Add(new POLine()
                {
                    SageSku = sageSku,
                    RequiredQty = quantity,
                    OnPOPQty = onPOPQty
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // Update existing record
                poLine.RequiredQty += quantity;
            }

            // Clean-up
            sageSku = null;
        }

        // Clean-up
        results = null;

        // Iterate through po lines
        foreach (POLine poLine in poLines)
        {
            dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();
            dataRow["sageSku"] = poLine.SageSku;
            dataRow["requiredQuantity"] = poLine.RequiredQty;
            dataRow["onPOPQuantity"] = poLine.OnPOPQty;
            dataRow["orderQuantity"] = (poLine.OnPOPQty > poLine.RequiredQty ? 0 : (poLine.RequiredQty - poLine.OnPOPQty));
            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowError("Failed to consolidate & populate purchase order lines by selected supplier.", ex);
    }

    // Set data source
    poLineList.DataSource = new DataView(dataTable);

    // Clean-up
    dataTable = null;
    dataColumn = null;
    dataRow = null;
    poLines = null;

    // Update column header text
    poLineList.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Sage Sku";
    poLineList.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Required Qty";
    poLineList.Columns[2].HeaderText = "On POP Qty";
    poLineList.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Suggested Order Qty";
}
```

When this code executes, I get the following error:

> Column requires a valid DataType.

What am I doing wrong here?

If I set the `orderQuantity` column's `DataType` to `System.Int32`, the datagrid view renders correctly with my data, but it's not editable:

[image]

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: The DataType property of a DataColumn doesn't support a datatype System.Windows.Forms.TextBox. I am a bit perplexed about the error message but this is definitively not a good value

Comment: Is there an alternative way to create an editable field if `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox` is not supported?

Comment: _DataGridView.Columns[x].ReadOnly = false;_

Comment: @Steve thanks, this did the trick for me, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this.

I kept the data type as `System.Int32` and then in the visual designer, I've clicked the `DataGridView` and ticked `Enable Editing` and then in the code that populates the datasource, I've added the following at the end:

```
// Disallow editting on certain columns
poLineList.Columns[0].ReadOnly = true;
poLineList.Columns[1].ReadOnly = true;
poLineList.Columns[2].ReadOnly = true;
```

I have 4 columns on my grid, so the above will make the first three as read only and the other columns editable, which is just the 4th column (which I wanted editable).

Thanks [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve).

Answer (score 0):

[As indicated in the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype(v=vs.110).aspx), a DataColumn.DataType only supports a specific set of data types (mostly primitive types, but there's a few exceptions). Unfortunately, you're not going to be able to add a TextBox directly like that.

However, have you looked into the [DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx)? You should be able to create your column as an instance of this class instead of a normal column that has been populated with a TextBox.

It may also be a possibility to create the DataGridView Template and have the desired column be one of this class (You can define the columns from the design view), while leaving the other columns empty shells that you populate in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I set the orderQuantity column's DataType to System.Int32, the datagrid view renders correctly with my data, but it's not editable:

in this case if your column is primary key it will not allow you to edit as it is a PK. make sure the editable column is not a PK.